# CORS issue with SignalR 2.2 on Azure

Tags: cors, signalr, signalr-hub

I am trying to Connect SignalR from my Angular2 for messaging.

I am getting error in chrome:

> `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://ls-dev-signalr.azurewebsites.net/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1…onData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22realtimemessaginghub%22%7D%5D&_=1490197517724. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

My SignalR configuration is in the OWIN Startup file which looks like this:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();

    var corsOption = new CorsOptions
        {
            PolicyProvider = new CorsPolicyProvider
            {
                PolicyResolver = context =>
                {
                    var policy = new CorsPolicy { AllowAnyOrigin = true, AllowAnyHeader = true, AllowAnyMethod = true };

                    return Task.FromResult(policy);
                }
            }
        };

    app.Map("/signalr", map =>
    {
        var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
            {
                EnableDetailedErrors = false,
                //EnableJSONP = true,
                EnableJavaScriptProxies = true,
            };
       map.UseCors(corsOption).RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
    });

    app.UseCors(corsOption);
    WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    app.UseWebApi(config);

}
```

I have researched lots of SO posts but did not have any success.

What should I do to enable CORS for SignalR?

**UPDATE from @ShaulBehr, who is working with the OP on this issue:**

We have narrowed the problem down to the fact that the browser client is not sending an `Origin` header when making the SignalR connection request.  We can repro this behavior in Postman: if you send an `Origin` header, the SignalR endpoint responds with an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.  If not, not.

The question (for bounty) now is:

- How do we get the client to send an `Origin` header?  **OR**
- How do we get the Azure site to respond with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header even if the `Origin` header is omitted from the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the HTTP spec (URL below):

> While following the requirements for cross-site access requests, user
>   agents must ensure that for each request (including redirects, et
>   cetera) the Origin HTTP request header is set, with the value set to
>   access control origin.

https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-access-control-20080912/#cross-site0

IIS respects the spec in this aspect as to only send the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header if the Origin request header is set.

That being said, it is possible, even if not recommended, to force the server to always set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header with each request by adding it as a custom header in your web.config file. 
You will also have to remove any entries in the Cors blade in the Azure portal.

To achieve this, you can add the following section to your web.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
         <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allowed-Origin" value="*" />
         </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you!  We were adding the custom headers before, but we hadn't removed the entries in the Cors blade in Azure.  That's what clinched it!

Answer (score 2):

I have always found that adding this section to the `web.config` file works best:

```
 <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
```

NOTE: These settings are "wide-open", accepting any callers.  You may need to be more restrictive in your use case.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Glenn, i tried but still getting CORS issue. not getting Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* in response headers

Comment: I'm working with @Kaushal on this.  Interesting added info: we tried adding other headers in that section, e.g. `<add name="foo" value="bar" />` and those headers were successfully returned.  But the special CORS headers were not returned.  There's obviously something blocking them from coming back.  Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using SignalR cross domain, and am also on v2.2. I'm using Angular 1.5 though. But if the problem is truly on the SignalR side, this should work.

```
  app.Map("/signalr", map =>
     {
        // Setup the CORS middleware to run before SignalR.
        // By default this will allow all origins. You can 
        // configure the set of origins and/or http verbs by
        // providing a cors options with a different policy.
        map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
        {
           EnableDetailedErrors = true
        };
        map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
     });
```

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for your answer.  We have narrowed down the problem to the fact that the browser client is not sending an `Origin` header in the connection request.  In Postman we have repro'd this: if we send an `Origin` header, we get back the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response.  If not, not.